# Liferay port 80 forwarding

Tags: apache, centos, liferay, catalina

I'm running CentOS on my server, and I want to forward port of Liferay portal from 8080 to 80. I've changed the server.xml file but I can not connect to portal. Log from Catalina.out is fine, it shows that server started up. I have got also installed httpd on CentOS. netstat -tulpn shows that port 80 is not in use.
I will be thankful for any guide or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best practice to have Apache or any other webserver of your choice serve port 80/443 and forward traffic to the application server. There's a lot of information all over the internet, my version is in [this blog article](https://www.liferay.com/en/web/olaf.kock/blog/-/blogs/securing-liferay-chapter-3-port-issues-and-http-https) and the related ones, linked at the bottom of the article.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved this problem by disabling Apache on the server. Also thank you for the information in the blog. It's really useful.